# Safari status bar resets to hidden

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, safari

This is regarding Safari 13.0.1 on macOS 10.14.6.

I turn the status bar on using **View** > **Show Status Bar**.

Then the status bar will be visible as a pop-over on the bottom left when I hover over links. (Always hover your links!)

After restarting or some other trigger, the status bar will then default to hidden. And I will need to repeat the **View** > **Show Status Bar** step.

How do I persist in my setting to show the status bar?